# How to use history.push from react-router dom in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

i want the user to navigate to url "/item/24" on clicking a button. for this i want to use history.push in reactrouter-dom

below is my code,

```
import { History } from 'history';

type Something = {
    history: History<any>; 
}
type DialogProps = {
    icon: React.ReactNode;
    isActive: boolean;
};

const Dialog: React.FC<Something & DialogProps> = ({
    icon,
    history,
}) => (
    <button onClick={()=> history && history.push( `/item/?itemId=${id}`)> 
        click
    </button>
);
```

but this gives typescript error like below

argument of type 'FC(Something & {icon: ReactNode is not assignable to parameter of type ElementType'

could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: why dont u create a method and call that method on button click and inside that method call history.push

Comment: thanks could you please add your answer. i am not sure why i get the typescript error.

Comment: Which file / line are you seeing this error : `FC(Something & {icon: ReactNode is not assignable to parameter of type ElementType`?

Comment: Instead of `Something`, do `import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom'` and use `RouteComponentProps`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Link component ?

```
<Link to="`/item/?itemId=${id}`">
    <button> 
        click
    </button>
</Link>
```

Comment: i have used link instead of button. but i have to use button for its reason of styling it

Answer (score 0):

What is the `7` on line 3? It should be `{`?

```
type Something = {
    history: History<any>; 
}
```

Replace comma `,` with semicolon `;`

```
type DialogProps = {
    icon: React.ReactNode;
    isActive: boolean;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `{ withRouter }` check this [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)

then you can check your props and then you will have your `history.push` in you `props`